# Two views trade layouts animated (including Z Order)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, nslayoutconstraint

I have two views, one an `UIImageView` which shows a user chosen photo and the other an `MKMapKitView` which shows a user chosen location of the object. At rest the views are arranged like so:

[image]

When the user taps on view 2, I would like the two to change places. And vice versa. Both views are positioned with constraints. So I could do an animation where I first fetched both sets of constraints, then cleared them, and then applied them in the flip order, but the z order wouldn't switch. Whichever view is in the "small" mode should aways be above the other.

I would really like to be able to animate it such that the swap is apparent. Somehow make it appear to rotate by doing something like:

[image]

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I tried the following:

```
- (IBAction)swapPreview {
    NSArray *photoConstraints = self.photoView.constraints;
    NSArray *mapConstraints = self.mapView.constraints;
    [self.photoView removeConstraints: photoConstraints];
    [self.mapView removeConstraints: mapConstraints];
    NSLog(@"photoConstraints %@", photoConstraints);
    NSLog(@"mapConstraints %@", mapConstraints);
    CGRect biggerFrame = CGRectUnion(self.photoView.frame, self.mapView.frame);
    CGRect upperFrame = CGRectOffset(RectCenterScaled(biggerFrame, 0.5), 0, biggerFrame.size.height / -4);
    CGRect lowerFrame = CGRectOffset(upperFrame, 0, upperFrame.size.height);
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4 delay: 0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.photoView.frame = upperFrame;
        self.mapView.frame = lowerFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        UIView *container = self.photoView.superview;
        [self.photoView addConstraints: mapConstraints];
        [self.mapView addConstraints: photoConstraints];
        [container exchangeSubviewAtIndex: [container.subviews indexOfObject: self.photoView] withSubviewAtIndex:[container.subviews indexOfObject: self.mapView]];
        [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.4 delay: 0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [container updateConstraints];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
    }];
}
```

But this breaks on the second animation block, when I try to swap the constraints. So what is the better way? I could traverse all of the constraints in the view hierarchy swapping any firstItem/secondItems that refer to the two views. But constraints that were local to the smaller view would need to change locality.

I'm beginning to wonder if I shouldn't just make a custom UIView subclass that has two children and do the layout directly, rather than mess with the constraint stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made test project and class which behave as you want:

```
@interface ViewController ()
                                                                  //initial constants values
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view1Top;//0
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view2Top;//20
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view1Left;//0
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view2Left;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view1Height;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view2Height;//100
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view1Width;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *view2Width;//50
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    //setting initial values for constraints related to view size
    self.view1Width.constant = self.self.view.frame.size.width;
    self.view1Height.constant = self.self.view.frame.size.height;
    self.view2Left.constant = self.view.frame.size.width - 20 - self.view2Width.constant;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender {

    CGFloat gap = 20.0;
    CGFloat height = (self.view.frame.size.height - 3*gap)/2; //height of views in the middle of animation
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width - 40; //width of views in the middle of animation
    self.view1Top.constant = gap;
    self.view1Height.constant = height;
    self.view2Top.constant = height + 2*gap;
    self.view2Height.constant = height;
    self.view1Left.constant = self.view2Left.constant = gap;
    self.view1Width.constant = self.view2Width.constant = width;

     [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
             } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

         [self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex: [self.view.subviews indexOfObject: self.view1] withSubviewAtIndex:[self.view.subviews indexOfObject: self.view2]];
                 self.view2Top.constant = 0;
                 self.view2Left.constant = 0;
                 self.view2Height.constant = self.view.frame.size.height;
                 self.view2Width.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;

                 self.view1Top.constant = gap;
                 self.view1Width.constant = 50;
                 self.view1Height.constant = 100;
                 self.view1Left.constant = self.view.frame.size.width - self.view1Width.constant - gap;

         [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0 animations:^{
             [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                    }];

     }];
}

@end
```

*view1* is the red view, *view2* is the blue one.

*animate* is an anction in my case initiated by button tap.

The key is not to removing constraints just animating constant properties.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` provides these:

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view;
- (void)sendSubviewToBack:(UIView *)view;
```

to control the Z-order of a view.

Use the in one of the animations' completion block. A good time to do that is when the views aren't overlapping.